# ROR find by sql to grab email addresses out of IBM iSeries (DB2)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ibm-midrange

We've been continuously working on this issue for a few months and not getting far with it. Since this was first asked, we changed the code (based on what the original developer for the site suggested), but we are still not getting where we need to be.

I'm relatively new to Ruby and am currently taking some courses to learn more about it, so please bear with me. We're using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3.2 We use AS/400 for our database. We've tried using Active Record for this before, and it doesn't want to work because of our versions of Ruby and Rails being older combined with getting it to connect with the 400.

We have an online ordering site that you have to have an account set up to access. Depending on what type of account you are set up as, you might have to have your order approved by someone. I.e. if I am a drop ship account, my distributor has to approve what I'm ordering. The way it had been set up, the distributor wasn't getting any kind of approval email.

Each account that requires approval has x number of email addresses attached to it of people who are able to approve the order. We have been told that `target_email` needs to be a string, so we tried numerous ways of making it a string to no avail. As is, it's only sending the first two email, not the approval email. If we run `target_email = Contact.find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 =''"]` in console, it returns the expected email addresses associated with that account. So we know that's working the way it should... but we're at a loss as to what is wrong with the rest of the code.

```
 # notify Customer
                Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("", "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation", email_details)               

                target_email = Contact.connection.select_values "SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 =''"

                # Order Approval
                if sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DS" or sign_on.acctypw1.strip == "DSD" 
                    # If there is no distributor email address, the mailer model will substitute in the admin's email from their settings
                     target_email.each do | email_address | Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(email_address, 'Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>', "Order Confirmation Approval", email_details)
                     end                 
                    # notify Coastal staff
                    Mailer.deliver_order_coastal_notify_email("", "Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>", "Order Confirmation-Notify Staff", email_details)                          
                    end
```

I tried

`target_email = Contact.connection.select_values("SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = act223").uniq`

This works but it sends emails to multiple accounts why this would happen? I think I need to set a value for act223

`act223 = "ACT223"`

`target_email = Contact.connection.select_values("SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = #{Contact.connection.quote(act223)}").uniq`

this throws `NameError (undefined local variable or method`act223' for #):`
in development.log.

Here is a link to the relevant [table data](http://www.coastalpet.com/edi/tabledata.htm) if more table information is needed just let me know and I can add it to that page. I am looking to do some sort of a join of a field from another table. In this same model I have SignOn.prefdstw1 which gets me the same account number is there a way to Join this field in the query with the 400?

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find_by_sql` always returns an array of model objects, so

```
Contact.find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 =''"]
```

is not an array of email addresses - it's an array of `Contact` objects, with only one object

You could either extract the email addresses from this, using something like

```
Contact.find_by_sql(["SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 =''"]).collect do |contract|
  contact.emal23
end
```

I'm not entirely sure what rails will do to the uppercased column name.

If you don't want to instantiate a whole Contact object just to get the email you could also do

```
Contact.where("ACT223 = ''").pluck('EMAL23')
```

which would return an array of emails, assuming that Rails knows that the correct table to use for this is WEBOEL23 - it's not clear to me whether that is the table for `Contact` (and thus you've use `set_table_name` to configure this) or whether `Contact` is just a random model unrelated to that table.

You could also drop down a level and do

```
Contact.connection.select_values "SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 =''"
```

which will also return an array of email addresses.

Comment: Oh man. Totally! I completely overlooked that target_email would be a list of `Contact`'s instead of an array of email addresses as stated by the author. BTW on an old Rails (as evidenced by the mailer syntax), `.pluck()` won't exist, but `.map{|c| c.emal23 }.compact` will work.

Comment: Pluck was definitely in 3.2 - I had apps on 3.2 until quite recently

Comment: the `Mailer.deliver_some_mailer_method` is Rails 2 syntax. Rails 3+ uses `Mailer.some_mailer_method().deliver`

Comment: Since the column you need is in uppercase, you can access it that way: `contact.EMAL23`. `contact['EMAL23']` also works.

Comment: target_email = Contact.connection.select_values "SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 ='30153'" worked perfectly and sent out all 4 of the emails from EMAL23 however when I pulled out the hardcoded value it did not send any of the emails from EMAL23 ACT223 =''"

Comment: What do you mean by "pulled out the hardcoded value"?

Comment: I had "hard coded" the account ACT223 ='30153'" when I run target_email = Contact.connection.select_values "SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 =''"  target_email.each do | email_address | Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(email_address, 'Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>', "Order Confirmation Approval", email_details)
 end     
 the emails did not pull like they do when there is a value for ACT223 but when I run it in console I  get [] which I think is correct?

Comment: This has way overgrown comments - I have no idea what you're doing

Comment: ok I tried to adjust the question to make it easier to see where I am. thanks again for all of your help!

Comment: `target_email = Contact.connection.select_values "SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = act223"` also works but it sends 10 copies of the emails any idea why this would happen?

Comment: @bobkendall RE 10 copies: That's because that select is returning all the email addresses that match that query, so if there are 10 rows where ACT223 = act223, even if all the EMAL23 email addresses are the same, you are still looping over each of them. You can eliminate duplicates with `.uniq`

Comment: ACT223 = act223.uniq generates an error in development.rb `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (S1000 (-5001) [IBM][iSeries Access ODBC Driver][DB2 UDB]SQL5001 - Column qualifier or table ACT223 undefined.):
` is there a better way to do it that the 400 can understand?

Comment: `Array#uniq` is a Ruby thing, not SQL. `target_email = Contact.connection.select_values("SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = act223").uniq`

Comment: that did generate less emails but it appears that it is pulling more than one account (ACT223) it is looping through the file (logical) and grabbing all of the accounts. My test account 30153 should have two emails not 12 how can I keep it from other accounts?

Comment: @bobkendall That would be an issue with your SQL query, which we can't help you with without seeing your schema and relevant rows.

Comment: I think I need a value for act223 `act223='something'` `target_email = Contact.connection.select_values("SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = act223").uniq` I am unsure what the something should be

Comment: @bobkendall It looks like that query will return all rows in the `EMAL23` table because of SQL case-insensitivity `WHERE ACT223 = act223` is the same as `WHERE ACT223 = ACT223`. If `act223` is supposed to be a ruby variable, then you need to interpolate it into the query like: `"SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = #{Contact.connection.quote(act223)}"`.

Comment: this makes sense but it throws an undefined local variable error any thoughts?

Comment: @bobkendall Yes, that won't work unless you have the local variable set. `act223 = 'something'` like you just said above.

Comment: that is why I wondering about a join on SignOn.prfdstw1 like I updated in the question

Comment: tried `act223 ="SignOn.prfdstw1"`
     
`target_email = Contact.connection.select_values("SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 = #{Contact.connection.quote(act223)}").uniq` no error but email did not go through

Comment: @Unixmonkey I am looking to do some sort of a join of a field from another table. In this same model I have SignOn.prefdstw1 which gets me the same account number is there a way to Join this field in the query with the 400?

Comment: @bobkendall Is that a Ruby method or an SQL table column? If it is a Ruby method that returns the account name, then `act223 = SignOn.prfdstw1` (without the quotes that you added above). If it is SQL, you'll have to figure it out yourself or start posting some schema and sample data.

Comment: Here is a link (http://www.coastalpet.com/edi/tabledata.htm) to the relevant table data if more table information is needed just let me know and I can add it to that page.

Comment: I have added example data for the fields in the tables that we are currently using.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `each` loop, `target_email` is a bareword variable (without quotes), but the first argument to the mailer is the string (within quotes) `'target_email'`.

Remove those quotes to get to this (whitespace added for readability):

```
target_email.each do | email_address |
  Mailer.deliver_order_distributor_approval_email(
    email_address,
    'Coastal Pet Online Ordering<noreply@coastalpet.com>',
    "Order Confirmation Approval",
    email_details
  )
end
```

Then the mailer should have access to the email address.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion that does make sense, however this did not change the result. In the development.log I can see where the other two email are bing sent and I do receive those but the one email that is supposed to pull emails from the DB is not being sent...and I am not sure why??

Comment: @bobkendall Is it `order_distributor_approval_email` that isn't getting delivered? Could we see the code for the mailer? Also, what does `target_email` look like (the `EMAL23` column in your db)?

Comment: I have added the mailer.rb code above EMAL23 is just a list of emails per account for the one test account i am using it has 5 emails in it.

Comment: to answer your earlier question yes, it is order_distributor_approval_email that is not being delivered

Comment: If the mailer is throwing an exception, your app might not be showing it to you. You may want to set `config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true` in the environment you are testing in (/config/environments/development.rb). Also check out [Pry](https://github.com/pry/pry#runtime-invocation) and pepper your mailer with `binding.pry` to inspect the state of things as the code is executed.

Comment: yes I had changed config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true a while back and I have gotten errors with it but with the current code I am not generating any errors. I will look into Pry though

Comment: curious...if I take target_email = Contact.find_by_sql ["SELECT EMAL23 FROM WEBOEL23 WHERE ACT223 =''"]
 and hard code an account I am able to send an email to order_distributor_approval_email but I do not receive the emails at the addresses but in the log I am seeing Sent mail to #<Contact:0x9e31f1c> where the email addresses should be listed. Also I am BCC on all the emails and for the approval email it is listed as to undisclosed recipients.

Comment: Sounds like you are zeroing in on it. Mail is being sent, but maybe not to any recipient? Maybe `target_email` isn't what you expect? (odd that you use `target_email` both inside and outside the block. I would change it to `email_address` or something inside the block to differentiate it from the array being looped over (as I edited my answer to reflect). Also, could it be being filtered to spam or blocked at the mailserver level?

Comment: yes thank you for that tip using email_address makes better sense. I have looked into the possibility of it being blocked at the mail server and the lotus admin says it isn't (he's picky about me browsing around in there)